# Linq query with two sub-queries that group by, one with an average, and one with a max

Tags: linq

I have a parent table, parentTable which may or may not have children in childTable.  I am looking to get average % complete of any given parent's children, and the MAX(due) (date) of the children where they exist.  My SQL is this:

```
SELECT parentRecord_id, assigned_to,
    (SELECT avg(complete) 
    FROM childTable
    WHERE parent_id = parentRecord_id
    and deleted IS NULL
    GROUP BY parent_id),
    (SELECT max(due) 
    FROM childTable
    WHERE parent_id = parentRecord_id
    and deleted IS NULL
    GROUP BY parent_id
    )
FROM parentTable s
WHERE s.deleted IS NULL and assigned_to IS NOT NULL
```

My result set gives me rows with either correct values for the average and max, or null.  In this instance I have to do follow up processing so I could ignore the null values if I was doing a foreach through DataTable rows.  However I am trying to do this in Linq and can't figure out how to avoid a System.InvalidOperationException where Linq is trying to cast null to a double.  Here is what I've tried so far.

```
var query8 = from s in db.parentTable
    where s.deleted == null
    select new
        {
            ID = s.assigned_to,
            Average =
                ((from t in db.childTable
                      where t.parent_id == s.strategy_id
                      group t by new { t.parent_id } into g
                      select new
                          {
                             a0 = g.Average(f0 => f0.complete )
                          }).FirstOrDefault().a0) 
                       };
foreach (var itm in query8)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("User id:{0}, Average: {1}", itm.ID, itm.Average));
    }
```

Here's my question.  How do I get the query to handle those returned rows where average complete or max due (date) are null?

Comment: What would be the correct thing for it to do if there is a null value? For example, if there were values `{1,2,null}`, would the average be `1.5` or `1`, or some other value?

Answer (score 0):

You can either filter out the records where the values are null (by another condition) or if you want to include them do something like this:

```
a0 = g.Average(f0 => f0.complete.HasValue? f0.complete: 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would cast the list to nullable double before calling Average/Max like so:

```
var query8 = 
    from s in db.parentTable          
    where s.deleted == null
    select new
    {
      ID = s.assigned_to,
      Average =
        from t in db.childTable
        where t.parent_id == s.strategy_id
        group t by t.parent_id into g
        select g.Cast<double?>().Average(f0 => f0.complete)
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming complete is a Nullable, you should be able to do:

```
var query8 = from s in db.parentTable
    where s.deleted == null
    select new
        {
            ID = s.assigned_to,
            Average =
                ((from t in db.childTable
                      where t.parent_id == s.strategy_id
                         && s.complete.HasValue()
                      group t by new { t.parent_id } into g
                      select new
                          {
                             a0 = g.Average(f0 => f0.complete )
                          }).FirstOrDefault().a0) 
                       };
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who responded.

I was unable get around the null anonymous issue with the basic query as I had it, but adding a join to the childTable eliminated the nulls.

Another solution is to use a from x in g.DefaultIfEmpty clause.

```
var query8 =
    from st in db.tableParent
    select new { Ass = st.assigned_to ,
        Avg = 
        (from ta in db.tableChild
         group ta by ta.parent_id into g
         from x in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select g.Average((f0=>f0.complete))).FirstOrDefault()
     };
```